# when I click on one of my links, it shows me error 404|not found. I tried some tricks like php artisan optimize /php artisan route:list

Tags: php, laravel

in my EnseignantController

```php
public function add_enseignant_form(){
    return view ('enseignant_add');
   // return redirect ('/');
}
```

Route web

```php
Route::get('/enseignant/add',[EnseignantController::class, 'add_enseignant_form'])->name('enseignant.form');
```

link in vue enseignant_add.blade.php

```html
<a href="{{route('enseignant.form')}}">Add Enseignant</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a route looking like this `/enseignant/{id}` placed **before** `/enseignant/add` In such case, `add` would be interpreted as `id`

Comment: thank you @ClémentBaconnier that resolved my error it was exactly as you just said

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you get is incorrect.

The path you request does not exist.